# Retrieve document from collection in azure function cosmosdb trigger

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have created an azure function that gets triggered when a new document is added to a collection.

```
public static void Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> input, ILogger log)
{
if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
{
    log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + input.Count);
    log.LogInformation("First document Id " + input[0].Id);
}}
```

Is it possible to select a particular document from this collection and then query the data in that selected document?

Eg. in the collection called clothescollection, i have a document that has an id:12345Tops. I want to query the data found in the document with the id:12345Tops.

Or alternatively retrieve the 1st document in the collection, and then query that 1st selected document

i have viewed azure functions with http triggers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#trigger---attributes

but i need to use cosmosdb trigger as this needs to be triggered when a document is added to the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to query documents on a second collection based on the changes that happen on a first collection?

That is certainly doable, you need to use a [Cosmos DB Input Binding and pull the `DocumentClient` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#http-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-documentclient-c).

The code would look something like:

```
[FunctionName("CosmosTrigger")]
public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "ToDoItems",
        collectionName: "Items",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",
        LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
        CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, 
    [CosmosDB(
        databaseName: "ToDoItems",
        collectionName: "CollectionToQuery",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")] DocumentClient client,
    ILogger log)
{
    foreach (var documentInsertedOrUpdated in documents)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do a read document on another collection
            var otherDocument = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("ToDoItems", "CollectionToQuery", "some-id-maybe-taking-it-from-the-documentInsertedOrUpdated"));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError(ex, "Failed to process document");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. No, i want to select a particular document from a collection and query that data in that particular document. This will be done in Azure Function cosmosdb trigger

Comment: The Trigger sends a batch of documents, as I showed in the response, you can then use a DocumentClient to do whatever operation you want, it can be a query, or if you want to read a single document, you can do a `ReadDocumentAsync` instead of the `CreateDocumentQuery`.

Comment: if you do not know the id of the required document but you know the id contains tops, would it be possible to retrieve that document? Thanks

Comment: Then you can do a query as my initial sample had, with a CONTAINS filter in the WHERE. At that point you have the DocumentClient to issue all the queries/reads that you require based on the information coming from the Trigger

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to call CosmosDb to retrieve the full document from a CosmosDb trigger.

You should be able to get the json and deserialize to the type that you want. 
Please see the below sample function.

You could just do ToString() to extract the document content from the list of documents that's being passed to the function. Or you could directly deseralize the json into an object that you have.

```
public static class CosmosDbAuditFunction
{
    [FunctionName("CosmosDbAuditFunction")]
    public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "DBNAME",
        collectionName: "COLLECTIONNAME",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString",
        LeaseCollectionName = "LeaseCollection",
        CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]IReadOnlyList<Document> input, ILogger log)
    {
        if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
        {
            var changedDocumentjson = input[0].ToString();               
        }
    }
}
```